# tinymce 4: how to create your own file manager?

Tags: jquery, file-manager, tinymce-4

I am trying to make my own file browser so that I can select the image from my file manage and send it tinymce's image link's field, but I can't find any further information anywhere else on how I can achieve this.

This is the code to open up an new popup on top the insert/ edit image,

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {

    //tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    //console.log(field_name);

    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Browse Image',
        file: "yourbrowser.php?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url,
        width: 450,
        height: 305,
        resizable : "no",
        inline : "yes",
        close_previous : "no",
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Insert',
            classes: 'widget btn primary first abs-layout-item',
            disabled: true,
            onclick: 'close'
        }, {
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close',
            window : win,
            input : field_name
        }]
    });

    return false;
},
```

This is where I stuck - how can I select an image from my file manager and send it to the image link in insert/ edit image popup?

Below is my entire code so far,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.button').click(function(){

            // @reference: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.remove#
            if(tinyMCE.editors.length > 0) {

                // Remove all editors bound to textareas
                //tinymce.remove('textarea');

                // Remove all editors
                tinymce.remove();
            }

            $('.content').load('full.html', function() {

                if(tinyMCE.editors.length == 0) {

                    tinymce.init({
                        //selector: "textarea",
                        mode : "textareas",
                        editor_selector : "mce-customised",
                        editor_deselector : "not-editor",
                        theme: "modern",
                        plugins: [
                            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
                        ],
                        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
                        image_advtab: true,

                        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {

                            //tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                            //console.log(field_name);

                            tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                                title: 'Browse Image',
                                file: "yourbrowser.php?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url,
                                width: 450,
                                height: 305,
                                resizable : "no",
                                inline : "yes",
                                close_previous : "no",
                                buttons: [{
                                    text: 'Insert',
                                    classes: 'widget btn primary first abs-layout-item',
                                    disabled: true,
                                    onclick: 'close'
                                }, {
                                    text: 'Close',
                                    onclick: 'close',
                                    window : win,
                                    input : field_name
                                }]
                            });

                            return false;
                        },


                        // Specifying an Absolute Image Path
                        document_base_url : "http://localhost/test/2013/js/tinymce/tinymce_4.0.2/",
                        relative_urls : false,
                        remove_script_host : false,


                        image_list: "image_list.php",
                        link_list: "link_list.php"
                    });

                    $('.button-submit').submit_form();
                }

            });

            return false;
        });

    });
```

The [test site](http://lauthiamkok.net/bin/tinymce4/index.php).

Or, do you know any good file mananger plugin that works with tinymce?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser should give some insights.

Comment: thanks. seen and tested that one, it is for TinyMCE 3.x. i am working on TinyMCE 4....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should find usefull info here : [Configuration:file_browser_callback](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_browser_callback)

```
win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = 'my browser value';
```

and here : [tinymce forum](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=108477#p108477)